# Quill.js: registering PlainClipboard causes initial editor content to lose all formats

Tags: rich-text-editor, quill

The `PlainClipboard` shown in the [doc](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/#extending) is very useful when we want Quill to clear all formats when content is pasted (e.g., copied from webpages). But if we register this module as `'modules/clipboard'`, any formats in the initial editor container will be wiped out as well:

```
<div id="editor-container">
    <ol><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ol>
</div>
```

because the initial content is also processed by the `convert()` function when the editor is initialized. To workaround this, I used a flag to indicate whether it's editor initialization or normal user pasting:

```
var quill_initializing = true;

class PlainClipboard extends Clipboard {
    convert(html = null) {
        if (quill_initializing) {
            quill_initializing = false;
            return super.convert(html);
        } else {
            if (typeof html === 'string') {
                this.container.innerHTML = html;
            }
            let text = this.container.innerText;
            this.container.innerHTML = '';
            return new Delta().insert(text);
        }
    }
}
```

This works for Quill 1.3.1 but after I updated to Quill 1.3.2, this approach stops working.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hmm your code does seem to be working in Quill's playground for 1.3.2? https://codepen.io/quill/pen/BwzwKm

Comment: @jhchen I noticed you used `Quill.register(PlainClipboard);`, but since my intention was to remove all formatting, I used `Quill.register('modules/clipboard', PlainClipboard, true);` to replace the original clipboard module. This way it's pretty tricky to have the initial editor container untouched.